# Approximating a function which has small derivatives

Tags: derivatives, approximation, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have some function $f(t) = f(a(t),b(t),c(t))$ which I want to evaluate at all times $t$.

Now, I know that in general function $c(t)$ varies very quickly ($\dot{c}(t)$ is large) whilst the functions $a(t), b(t)$ vary slowly.

If we say the timescale of the variation in $c$ is $T_c$ and analogously for $a, b$,timescale $T_{ab}$ then,

$$ \epsilon = \frac{T_c}{T_{ab}} << 1$$

How can I approximate/expand $f(t)$ in terms of $\epsilon$, accounting for the different timescales over which the variations occur? Since $a(t), b(t)$ are approximately constant for a $\delta t$ it seems there should be a way to approximate for this. I have been reading about [methods of multiple scales](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m204/ch6.pdf) but this seems more geared towards solving ODEs?

Thanks

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but even if $\dot a=\dot b=0$, there is no way to know the value $f(a,b,t)$ without knowing something about the value of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Well if you have the initialisation of $a,b$ i.e. $a(0), b(0)$ then the zero derivative case is ok?